# Ionic run android - Internal Error

Tags: android, ionic-framework, npm

I am unable to run Ionic project in windows. Command "ionic run android" shows the following error.

**Error**

```
shell.js: internal error

Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked
```

Comment: Try removing platform and add again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced the Same Issue ,

Steps

```
> 1 .Remove Anti-virus ,
> 2. Just Reboot the system 
> 3. If that does not work reinstall the node https://nodejs.org/en/download/
```