# How to release resource \AppData\Local\Temp\shelljs_60d55c70cdc922162f4b without removing antivirus or reinstalling node?

Tags: node.js, windows, process, resources, ionic2

I'm running Ionic2 to build windows app. but it is giving me following error:

```
shell.js: internal error
Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, open 'C:\Users\edge\AppData\Local\Temp\shelljs_60d55c70cdc922162f4b'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:640:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1333:33)
    at execSync (C:\Users\edge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\shelljs\src\exec.js:67:57)
    at Object._exec (C:\Users\edge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\shelljs\src\exec.js:179:12)
    at Object.exec (C:\Users\edge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\shelljs\src\common.js:168:23)
    at Object.gatherGulpInfo (C:\Users\edge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\lib\info.js:201:24)
    at Object.t (C:\Users\edge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\utils\stats.js:148:15)
    at Object.run (C:\Users\edge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\cli.js:135:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\edge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic:13:10)
```

I sow a same error:
[Ionic run android - Internal Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39146976/ionic-run-android-internal-error)

But I don't want to remove my antivirus and reinstall nodeJS.

> But when I restart my system and immediately after I run the command It works(Possibly some process takes time to execute which one access this resource)

Snapshot of process running on my system are as follows:

[image: process1]
[image: process2]
[image: process3]
[image: process4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue , and resolved it by uninstalling bytefence anti malware . it actually use the same resource mentioned above .(I checked in dell laptop)